# Mid line through a set of dicom images in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, line, dicom

I have a set of Dicom images on matlab and i would like to add a midline going through all the images
I am outputting the images via imshow3d function

thanks

Edit: here's what i have, the random points are not in the middle they just run through the image

```
>> clc;

>>clear;

>>%imports dicom images

>>run DicomImport.m;

>>%random points for shortest distance test

>>a = [1 10 200];

>>b = [500 512 300];

>>ab = b - a;

>>n = max(abs(ab)) + 1;

>>s = repmat(linspace(0, 1, n)', 1, 3);

>>for d = 1:3

  >>  s(:, d) = s(:, d) * ab(d) + a(d);

>>end



>>s = round(s);

>>Z = 593; 

>>N = 512;

>>X = zeros(N, N, Z);

>>X(sub2ind(size(X), s(:, 1), s(:, 2), s(:, 3))) = 1;

>>C = find(X);

>>ans.Img(C) = 5000;


>> %shows image

>>imshow3D(ans.Img);
```

Comment: That's great. What have you tried?

Comment: so i can pick two points and can create a shortest distance line in 3d which is fine but i wanted it to go through every slice. I can also add a line myselft using the insert tab when the image is outputted to me but i dont wanna eye ball it haha

Comment: Why don't you show us some code to illustrate what you have tried?

Comment: take a look, ive added some of my code

Comment: Can you describe what midline means here?  Do you mean to draw a 3D line from the middle of the first slice, down through the slices to the middle of the last slice?

Comment: Not quite, that i can do with my code atm. Imagine taking every image and drawing a line down the middle (y axis).

Comment: What colour should this line be? So you want a vertical line drawn in the middle of each image?

Comment: so for example the red line on image on the top right but for each slice
http://www.scielo.br/img/revistas/dpjo/v19n2//2176-9451-dpjo-19-02-00090-gf01.jpg

Comment: yeah! color doesnt matter

Comment: Your code is a bit unclear.  Which variable contains the stack of images?  Think of me as someone who can't invest a lot of time into your code.  You gotta make it easy for me to understand what you're doing.

Comment: haha sorry bout that. The dicom image function imports a set of images from a folder and the imshow3d fucntion previews them.

Comment: ok. Are your DICOM images grayscale or colour?  It looks like your DICOM image stack is stored in `ans.Img`.  This is a 3D matrix right?  Sorry I've never used DICOM images before.

Comment: no worries I'm new to them myself, they are in grayscale and yes they are stored as ans.Img and that is the 3D matrix

Comment: Gotcha.  Let me write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like `ans.Img` contains the 3D matrix consisting of your image stack.  It looks like you've got something going, but allow me to do this a bit differently.  Basically, you need to generate a set of coordinates where we can access the image stack and draw a vertical line in the middle of the each image in the image stack.  Do something like this.  First get the dimensions of the stack, then determine the halfway point for the columns.  Next, generate a set of coordinates that will draw a line down the middle for one image.  After you do this, repeat this for the rest of the slices and get the column major indices for these:

```
%// Get dimensions
[rows,cols,slices] = size(ans.Img);

%// Get halfway point for columns
col_half = floor(cols/2);

%// Generate coordinates for vertical line for one slice
coords_middle_row = (1:rows).';
coords_middle_col = repmat(col_half, rows, 1);

%// Generate column major indices for the rest of the slices:
ind = sub2ind(size(ans.Img), repmat(coords_middle_row, slices, 1), ...
             repmat(coords_middle_col, slices, 1), ...
             reshape(kron(1:slices, ones(rows, 1)), [], 1));

%// Set the pixels accordingly
ans.Img(ind) = 5000;
```

Comment: ahh well done. I think I misunderstood what the OP wanted lol.

Comment: No that's actually some very decent code.  You're doing what I did but it's wrapped in a nice GUI.

Comment: @TaimoorKhan - No worries.  Consider accepting one of our answers when you're ready.  This tells the StackOverflow community that you no longer need help.  This is done by clicking on the checkmark icon at the top of either post, to the left below the up and down arrows.  Good luck!

Comment: thanks again! Just a quick question about your code. would it be possible move the line along the x axis to offset it from the middle? so instead of it going down the middle it would go down any point i choose?

Comment: @TaimoorKhan - So you'd like a horizontal line where the vertical coordinate is of your choosing?... or do you wish to offset the horizontal coordinate of where the vertical line is being drawn?  The first option is a bit more work.  The second option is to simply modify the `col_half` variable to any column of your choosing, provided that it's contained within the image.

Answer (score 1):

This code is quite similar to the answer I provided to one of your earlier question; i.e. I don't use `imshow3D` but the framework is similar and simpler to modify in order to suit your need. In this case, upon pressing a pushbutton a line appears at the middle of the stack and you can scroll through it with the slider. I hope this can be of help.

```
function LineDicom(~)
clc
clear
close all

%// Load demo data
S = load('mri');

%// Get dimensions and number of slices.
ImageHeight = S.siz(1); %// Not used here
ImageWidth = S.siz(2); %// Not used here
NumSlices = S.siz(3);

S.D = squeeze(S.D);

%// Create GUI
hFig = figure('Position',[100 100 400 400],'Units','normalized');

%// create axes with handle
handles.axes1 = axes('Position', [0.2 0.2 0.6 0.6]);

%// create y slider with handle
handles.y_slider = uicontrol('style', 'Slider', 'Min', 1, 'Max', NumSlices, 'Value',1, 'Units','normalized','position', [0.08 0.2 0.08 0.6], 'callback', @(s,e) UpdateY);
handles.SlideryListener = addlistener(handles.y_slider,'Value','PostSet',@(s,e) YListenerCallBack);

%// Create pusbutton to draw line
handles.DrawLineButton= uicontrol('style', 'push','position', [40 40 100 30],'String','Draw line', 'callback', {@DrawLine,handles});

%// Flag to know whether pushbutton has been pushed
handles.LineDrawn = false;

%// Show 1st slice
imshow(S.D(:,:,1))

guidata(hFig,handles);

%// Listeners callbacks followed by sliders callbacks. Used to display each
%// slice smoothly.
    function YListenerCallBack

        handles = guidata(hFig);

        %// Get current slice
        CurrentSlice = round(get(handles.y_slider,'value'));

        hold on
        imshow(S.D(:,:,CurrentSlice));

        %// If button was button, draw line
        if handles.LineDrawn
            line([round(ImageWidth/2) round(ImageWidth/2)],[1 ImageHeight],'Color','r','LineWidth',2);
        end
        drawnow

        guidata(hFig,handles);

    end

    function UpdateY(~)

        handles = guidata(hFig); %// Get handles.
        CurrentSlice = round(get(handles.y_slider,'value'));

        hold on
        imshow(S.D(:,:,CurrentSlice));

        if handles.LineDrawn
            line([round(ImageWidth/2) round(ImageWidth/2)],[1 ImageHeight],'Color','r','LineWidth',2);
        end
        drawnow

        guidata(hFig,handles);

    end

%// Pushbutton callback to draw line.
    function DrawLine(~,~,handles)

        line([round(ImageWidth/2) round(ImageWidth/2)],[1 ImageHeight],'Color','r','LineWidth',2);

        handles.LineDrawn = true;
        guidata(hFig,handles);
    end

end
```

Sample output:

[image]

and after moving the slider up:

[image]

Is this what you meant? If not I'll remove that answer haha and sorry.